# Differential equation with $y' \cdot x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

During another engineering problem I have encountered the following differential equation $$ y'=\frac{21y+9x}{y+21x} $$

I'm only familier with solving using seperation of the variables but here I have an item of type $y\cdot x$ and $y \cdot y'$ so im not sure how to deal with it.

I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let $y = xu \implies y' = u + xu'$.

Comment: @mattos I tried the substitution $y=xf(x) $ and got here $ \left(xf\left(x\right)\right)'=\frac{21f\left(x\right)+9}{f\left(x\right)+21} $. How can I continue?

Comment: This type may be in your DE textbook under the heading "first order homogeneous (of degree zero)".

Comment: This is a homogeneous equation. You can determine whether or not an equation is homogeneous by replacing $x$ and $y$ with $kx$ and $ky$ for an arbitrary non-zero constant $k$. i.e. given $y'=f(x,y)$, $f(kx,ky)=f(x,y)$ implies $y'=f(x,y)$ is homogeneous. This means that you can write $f(x,y) = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$. Therefore you can substitution $y(x)=z(x)x$ and rewrite your equation as $xz' = F(z) - z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

As suggested by @mattos, the proposed ODE is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
(xu)' = \frac{21u + 9}{u + 21} & \Longleftrightarrow xu' + u - \frac{21u + 9}{u + 21} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow xu' + \frac{u^{2} - 9}{u + 21} = 0
\end{align*}

which is separable.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so. So we get $ x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{9-u^{2}}{u+21} $  $ \Rightarrow\frac{u+21}{9-u^{2}}=\frac{1}{x}dx $  $ \Rightarrow3\ln|u+3|-4\ln\left(|u-3|\right)=\ln\left(x\right)+C $ And now I have to solve for $u$ ?

Comment: @FreeZe Yes, that is the point.